# Regex: Match multiple strings with single regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract string based on below two strings. I should be able to match one of the available text.
Input strings are:

1. `//management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/serverName/databases/databaseName?api-version=2017-12-01`
2. `//management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/serverName?api-version=2017-12-01`

Based on whichever string (from above 2) is available, i should be able to extract either `Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/serverName/databases` (from 1st string) or `Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers` (from 2nd string).

The input strings are not in order of input.

**Edit**:
The input string can also be like:

1. `//management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/accountName/apis/sql/databases/databaseName?api-version=2015-04-08`

in the above sample string i would need to extract "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/accountName/apis/sql/databases"

I have tried this: `(Microsoft.[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+)|(Microsoft.[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+)` and it didnt work

Comment: use the alternation operator ``|``

Comment: I have tried this:
(Microsoft.[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+)|(Microsoft.[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+)
and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex

```
Microsoft\.DBforPostgreSQL\/servers(?:/serverName/databases)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/z0hGRa/1

Comment: Only "Microsoft." can be used as it is and not the rest of the string. Sorry i missed to mention this. The input also be something like below
1. //management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/accountName/apis/sql/databases/databaseName?api-version=2015-04-08

Answer (score 0):

this is the Regex you want:

```
(Microsoft\.DBforPostgreSQL/.*)/.*\?.*
```